# How to grab serialized in http request claims in a code using WIF?

Tags: single-sign-on, wif, adfs2.0, ws-federation

ADFS 2.0, WIF (WS-Federation), ASP.NET: There is no http modules or any IdentityFoundation configuration defined in a web.config (like most WIF SDK samples show), instead everything is done via program code manually using WSFederationAuthenticationModule, ServiceConfiguration and SignInRequestMessage classes. I do http redirect to ADFS in a code and it seems to work fine, returning claims and redirecting user back to my web site with serialized claims in http request. So the question is how to parse this request using WIF classes, properties and methods and extract claims values from there? Thanks

Comment: Can I ask why you're avoiding the modules and configuration?  Seems like you're reinventing the wheel to some degree.

Comment: It's a long story. Shortly speaking we're already having legacy mechanism of user authentication, that we're going to keep using. SSO is an alternative provided for users and the idea is to implement WS-Fed SSO in a single page/service to grab claims and convert them into our own made authentication system and leave the rest of our system untouched. So that what we are doing now is a kind of conversion WS-Def SSO (ADFS, WIF) to our own legacy authentication system. We do not want MS http modules like WSFederationAuthenticationModule to work and control authentication, we already have our own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case want to share my experience, it might help somebody in the future. Well, solution I finally came to looks like this:

```
 var message = SignInResponseMessage.CreateFromFormPost(Request) as SignInResponseMessage;

 var rstr = new WSFederationSerializer().CreateResponse(message, new WSTrustSerializationContext(SecurityTokenHandlerCollectionManager.CreateDefaultSecurityTokenHandlerCollectionManager()));

 var issuers = new ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry();
 issuers.AddTrustedIssuer("630AF999EA69AF4917362D30C9EEA00C22D9A343", @"http://MyADFSServer/adfs/services/trust");

 var tokenHandler = new Saml11SecurityTokenHandler {CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None};   
 var config = new SecurityTokenHandlerConfiguration{
     CertificateValidator = X509CertificateValidator.None,
     IssuerNameRegistry = issuers};

 config.AudienceRestriction.AllowedAudienceUris.Add(new Uri("MyUri"));
 tokenHandler.Configuration = config;
 using(var reader=XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(rstr.RequestedSecurityToken.SecurityTokenXml.OuterXml)))
   {
     token = tokenHandler.ReadToken(reader);
   }
 ClaimsIdentityCollection claimsIdentity = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token);
```

I found few similar code that uses SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration (it contains token handlers) instead of Saml11SecurityTokenHandler to read and parse token, however it did not work for me because of certificate validation failure. Setting `SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration.CertificateValidator` to `X509CertificateValidator.None` did not help coz Security Token Handler classes uses their own handler configuration and ignores STS configuration values, at least if you specify configuration parameters through the code like I did, however it works fine in case configuration is defined in web.config.